# QT label setText() while preserving text formatting

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have designed a [label](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html) in QT Designer and need to [set the text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) from the cpp implementation. This works. But, the text formmatting (size and bold) is being removed.

How can I set the text while preserving the formatting done in the ui file?

Sample:

```
ui->label_version->setText(QString::fromStdString("1.0.0"));
```

Comment: Any reason for not simply doing `setText("1.0.0")`?

Comment: My original code did have a std::string in stead of "1.0.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the real issue. I had set the text formatting within the rich text editor. What I needed to do was to set the formatting for the label withing the QtWidget properties. When this was changed all was preserved when setting a new text.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet? I am not sure what do you mean... Qt designer does nothing more than what you claim to have done in code... what do you mean by "setting formatting in the QtWidget properties"? The only property you can set is "setTextFormat(Qt::RichText)" but that does not preserve formatting when you call "setText()" again (without the formatting in the string you pass)

Comment: I agree with @dkish, the accepted answer explanation is not clear at all. I have the same problem but I don't know how to apply the fix. Please, clarify it

Answer (score 1):

You can open your `ui` file with text editor to check what test is set. In real Qt uses HTML to format text. Also, you can set [stylesheet](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

To save formatting you can try this:
1. Set text "%1" in `ui`
2. Save text before the change
3. Use saved text + `.arg` to set new text

```
Constructor()
{
    this->m_savedText = m_ui->myLabel->text();
    m_ui->myLabel->setText(this->m_savedText.arg("Default text"));
}

handler()
{
    m_ui->myLabel->setText(this->m_savedText.arg("New text"));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the current formatting and set it again after the text has been changed? I would like the cpp file to be independent from the formatting done in the ui file... to minimise misunderstandings during development.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me is to set at the beginning (designer or with code) textFormat as PlainText, with that, whenever you setText, it keeps the format.

Answer (score -1):

Simply apply alignment properties within Qt Creator; a simple `text-align: center` does not suffice upon setting new text on existing Widget:

[QLabel Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPHKK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In what way does specifying a text alignment preserve the bold text and text size?

Comment: @DanielHedberg Previous answer on this forum already solves this issue, and you can apply it again with QLabel's properties, like the alignment. Simply modify the text HTML output format under `text`. You can add a simple `<b></b>` to your likings, preserving the bold style in that way, e. g.